# Understanding RSpec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been searching around for a while, and did not find a clear explanation about testing structure in RoR. (I'm learning with Michael Hartl's book).

1. Since I'm using rspec for testing, do I need to keep the "test" folder anymore ?
2. Is the "spec" folder structure strictly assigned to specific test purposes ?
3. When "generating" a test script, does it do something else than creating the script file ? (i.e. could I create it by hand ?)

The 2nd question comes from this error:

```
undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup: ...
```

which occurs as soon as my very simple test file is not in /spec/requests (but in /spec/views):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Home page" do

  subject { page }

###1
  describe "title" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Welcome') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Home') }

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No
2. See Below
3. No, only create the file

There is one specific folder structure you need to use in order to run Capybara acceptance tests. These are tests that have "visit" in them

Capybara 1.0

```
spec/requests
```

Capybara 2.0

```
spec/features
```

Comment: Now I understand the origin of my error message. Thanks for this very precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

1) No, you don't need the `test` folder. Only `spec`, unless you're using Test::Unit.

2) You can order `spec` however you want. The general suggested format is

```
spec/
  controllers/
  views/      
  models/ 
  lib/ #Only if you have stuff in lib you need to test    
  spec_helper.rb
```

with names like `spec/controllers/items_controller_spec.rb`, and `spec/models/item_spec.rb`

3) I'm not sure what you mean. For RSpec, you just need to make a file that uses its syntax to test certain pieces of your Ruby code. It doesn't create a script -- you do.

For your last question about `visit`:

It seems like you're trying to use a [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) method (`visit`). Capybara takes care of visiting your site in a browser, not RSpec.

Comment: Thank you for this precision about the roles of each tool. It makes things clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, my understanding is that the `test` folder is generally used for Test::Unit stuff. You can delete or keep it; doesn't hurt to leave it.
2. There's a pretty specific way they want you to organize that stuff. If you have `app/models/user.rb`, for example, your spec should be in `spec/models/user_spec.rb`.
3. I don't know of anything else it does besides creating the test script. You can totally create those by hand, and I do all the time.

Comment: Thanks for this usefull clarification.